# Configure Apache to use SQL Server authentication

Tags: sql-server, authentication, apache

I believe it's possible to configure Apache to use SQL Server for authentication. You supply the DB connection parameters and a query to run. I suppose the contract is something like:

If the query returns something the user is authenticated, and if the query results are empty, the user is unkown.

Does anyone know how I can configure this?

Comment: Probably better suited to ServerFault.com

Answer (score 1):

Apache supports [`mod_authn_dbd`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_authn_dbd.html) that supports authentication against a SQL driver, and [`mod_dbd`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dbd.html) to support various database drivers. There are various projects that bridge the Apache DBD Framework with the TDS protocol, thus allowing authentication against a SQL Server, like [odbc-dbd](http://code.google.com/p/odbc-dbd/wiki/Linux).

I'm not aware of anyone doing this in production, but it looks like theoretically is possible, all you have is to do is connect the dots.

Of course, we're talking here a true HTTP authentication scheme: [Basic](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_auth_basic.html) or [Digest](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_auth_digest.html). If you are interested in 'Forms' authentication, that is not HTTP authentication, that is some application behavior and as such is implemented in your app code, not in Apache.